# entity property that is nullable

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want my nhibernate entity property to be nullable.

the column is a nvarchar(MAX) in sql server, and it can be NULL.

How do I map this using the xml mapping?

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping it as `string`.

Answer (score 0):

`not-null="false"` should do the trick. Or leave it as-is since the default is to allow nulls.